# Meaning of'By the month of April'

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 'by the month of April'? Does it mean full month of April?

Comment: Can you give the full context?

Answer (score 2):

It is an ambiguous expression. If I say I will tell you 'by the month of April', some people might take it to mean .before April starts' i.e. by 1st April.

But it could just as easily mean 'at any time during the month of April'.

If I was working as a debt collector I would always ask for a more specific commitment.